# how to see the verbose output of a process that is running that writes to a file (shred)

Tags: strace, stdout, stderr, file-descriptors

I am running the shred command to securely wipe some storage.

I would like to see its progress, but have lost the ssh terminal that was running the command.

Is there a way that I can use to see the verbose output of the shred command from a new ssh terminal?

I have tried to hook into and view the output from /proc/pid/fd/0 1 2 etc but it just shows the random characters from /dev/urandom.  I tried using strace, but the same file descriptors were available, with the same results.   Shred shows 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 fd, but they are all showing the random output.

MTIA, waiting patiently with stethoscope against drive...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-do-i-attach-a-terminal-to-a-detached-process

Comment: Using «ps -eaf | grep shred» may show you the shred command parameter and may where output was redirected if on command line.

Comment: ps -eaf just lists the command and flags that were used to invoke the process.  I am going to try and get the stackexchange link to work now.

Comment: no joy.  and reptyr command doesn't work because shred uses subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (since OP mentioned /proc/pid/fd/0 which is a Linux thing), for any tool that is doing sequential operations, the method below in 3 steps can be used:

1. Figure out the PID of the tool

   eg:

   ```
   # pgrep ^shred$
   699
   ```
2. Note for this PID the file descriptor(s) of interest that is reading or writing

   For example with `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd/` or `stat -c %N /proc/<pid>/fd/<FD>` or `lsof ...` ...

   Example:

   ```
   # ls -l /proc/699/fd/
   total 0
   lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 24 11:40 0 -> /dev/pts/6
   lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 24 11:40 1 -> /dev/pts/6
   lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 24 11:40 2 -> /dev/pts/6
   l-wx------ 1 root root 64 May 24 11:40 3 -> /dev/loop7
   ```

   Here the FD of interest is 3. It could have been FD 4 (like appears to be OP's case in [this comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/1131811/how-to-see-the-verbose-output-of-a-process-that-is-running-that-writes-to-a-file/1131835?noredirect=1#comment1475785_1131835)) or any other, depending on the command, the version of this command or its options when invoked.
3. Query the kernel, using [`/proc/<pid>/fdinfo/<fd>`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) about additional information:

   > `/proc/[pid]/fdinfo/` (since Linux 2.6.22)
   >
   > [...] The files in this directory are readable only by the owner of the process.

   (or by *root* or at least a process with the adequate capability.)

   > The contents of each file can be read to **obtain information
   > about the corresponding file descriptor**. [...]

   > The fields are as follows:
   >
   > `pos` This is a decimal **number showing the file offset**.
   > [...]

   For example:

   ```
   # cat /proc/699/fdinfo/3
   pos: 286785536
   flags:   0140001
   mnt_id:  830
   ino: 39
   ```

   or:

   ```
   # awk '/^pos:/ { print $2 }' /proc/699/fdinfo/3
   286785536
   ```

   So in this example `shred` is currently writing at position 286785536 ( ~ 273MiB).

This method doesn't require any cooperation from the tool: it doesn't have to be run in a terminal, be run in verbose mode, have any text output anywhere, log anything anywhere, to support handling a special signal (like `dd` does) to dump information, nor be `ptrace()`-ed: the kernel provides the current information through `/proc`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried examining the file descriptors.  I have the following:
```lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 23 11:06 0 -> '/dev/pts/0 (deleted)'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 23 11:06 1 -> '/dev/pts/0 (deleted)'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 23 11:06 2 -> '/dev/pts/0 (deleted)'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May 23 11:06 3 -> /dev/urandom
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 May 23 16:45 4 -> /dev/sda```
It might be because I tried reading with strace...

Comment: So it's obviously FD number 4 in your case: /dev/sda . Did you read the last part of my answer, with `fdinfo` (not just `fd`)?

Comment: I missed the fdinfo, as you suggested, but I get only the following:
```pos: 0
flags: 02004001
mnt_id: 13
ino: 27936```    and it doesn't seem to change.  The other fdinfos are the same.

Comment: Considering the example I provided was with really using the `shred` command and observing what it's doing, I'm a bit surprised your shred command is doing nothing and didn't even start doing anything (pos: 0). Did you use cat /proc/PID/fdinfo/4  (with the correct pid and the fd number 4, not 3)?

Comment: I think there is a problem on your system, but I'd rather not help debug, because I don't want to risk giving the wrong command that would affect something else.

Comment: According to top, shred is working away, and I used the correct pid, and tried all the fdinfos, which read almost exactly the same, the fdinfo in the above comment is 4.   Its a raspberry py 2b, so running a 32 bit debian, I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, now I take a closer look, there is some system error/misconfiguration.   I will reinstall.  Thanks for your help.